# css styling issue, for buttons

Tags: html, css

Ive been trying to give style to button, The code that I ve used is

```
#srchBtn
{
    width:120px;
    height:25px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size:15px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px pink, inset 0 -5px 15px orange, 0 2px 1px black;
   -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px pink, inset 0 -5px 15px orange, 0 2px 1px black;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px pink, inset 0 -5px 15px orange, 0 2px 1px black;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px pink, inset 0 -5px 15px orange, 0 2px 1px black;
}
```

but it takes away the clickable property of button, it acts like an image. when we try clicking on it, it doesnt act like a button.. what could be wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you change the appearance of a button, you will also need to change it for the pseudoclasses `:active` and `:hover` to have it *work* as a normal button.

That is to say, your button in fact is a button but it doesn't know what it looks like while clicked (`:active`) or on mouseover (`:hover`).

```
#srchBtn:hover {
    /* your code here */
}

#srchBtn:active {
    /* your code here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By "act like a button", do you mean makes it looks like clickable?

Most possibly because the button does not have its active (clicked) state. Normally, un-styled button will have its active state, styled by the browser the user is using. But since you already styled almost every aspect of your button, the browser won't add additional styling.

To add your own active (clicked state), use this:

`#srchBtn:active {  }`

You could also add its hover-ed state with this:

`#srchBtn:hover {  }`

Answer (score 0):

Is it a javascript function you are calling? If so checkout the script is loaded to your html page and try also with little css properties just width and height, see weather it works or not.

Comment: no javascript. did you try copying the css?? if uve , u cud see that the button act as a plain image. when you click on it, visually nothing hppens.

Comment: You mean it doesn't "depress" when you click on it? That's normal for styled buttons. You have to animate it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

i'd take away the id element, and make it a class. just in case you decide to have more than one button on your page. then you can keep all the buttons on your site uniform and intuitive.

```
.srchBtn{} //also include cursor:pointer

.srchBtn:hover{}
```